# AS3 Event Handler stuck in infinite loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I have a problem with my event handler. I am trying to use URLRequest to load some data from a database. But it's stuck in an infinite loop. Any suggestion of why is it looping, even after all the data is loaded?

The result is pushed into an array.

Code:

```
public function Listingdetailinfo()
{
    somedata = SearchVectorTest.lists;
    SrSend = new URLRequest("http://testurl/requestimage.php");
    SrSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    Arvariables = new URLVariables  ;
    SrSend.data = Arvariables;
    SaLoader = new URLLoader();
    SaLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

    Arvariables.data1 = somedata[0];

    SaLoader.load(SrSend);
    SaLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,Asandler);

    function searchVOs( pic:String )
    {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    function Asandler(event:Event):void
    {
        trace(event.target.data);
        // retrieve data from php call
        var resultString:String = event.target.data;

        trace(event.target.data);

        // parse result string as json object and cast it to array
        var resultArray:Array = JSON.parse(resultString) as Array;

        var len:int = resultArray.length;

        trace(resultString);

        // create vector of SearchVO
        var searchVOs:Array = new Array();

        // get the length of the result set
        var i:int;
        for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            searchVOs[i] = new Listingdetailinfo();
            searchVOs[i].pic = resultArray[i].pic;

            myArray.push(searchVOs[i].pic);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try harder on code formatting. I fixed it for you in another question. It is very hard to read such code like above

Comment: Hi, sorry, when i copy the code over, the format gone all crazy. But i dont have any frame. I just tried the code above, without anything else, just tried loading the data. and it still stuck in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code represents the constructor of Listingdetailinfo class. The reason of your "infinite loop" is that you are creating new instances of this class in

```
searchVOs[i] = new Listingdetailinfo();
```